# Collocation for perception

Tags: single-word-requests

Considering the sentence:

> Investor perception on active funds will be ______ too expensive.

I am struggling to find the right wording. The message is clear in my mind, but I can't make it clear with grammar or word choice. The above is the closest I got.

The message is supposed to be investors will think active funds will be too expensive. I just want to change it a bit so I use the smarty-pants phrase "investor perception." However, I can't seem to make the rest of the sentence coordinate.

### Question

Is there an appropriate word choice for this sentence and maintain a formal/professional tone?

**Note:** You may take slight creative liberties with the other portions of the sentence if need be.

Comment: The question is why you think the fashionable abstract phrase is preferable to your own perfectly clear way of saying it.  Your discomfort might be a justified rebellion against a pandemic of abstraction.  “Investors will judge active funds to be overpriced” is clear and strong.

Comment: Inserting a phrase like "investor perception" works best if you have a more complex sentence.  For example, *We are struggling with investor perception of overvaluing* or *We are struggling with investor perceived overvaluing of active funds*.  Sorry, I don't know what *active funds* are.  But now hopefully you see the trick to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction of your current example sentence can't work (regardless of what word you drop into the blank spot) because it makes *investor perception* the object of the verb. It would say that it's investor perception that's too expensive—not the active funds.

If you need to keep *investor perception*, then simply forget about another verb in the location you give, and use the following phrasing:

> **Investor perception** will be that active funds are too expensive.

---

If you are still looking for a verb to fit with *too expensive*, then you need to drop the use of *perception* and use something like this:

> Active funds will be **considered** too expensive by investors.
>   Active funds will be **found** too expensive by investors.

Or, if you don't like the passive construction and want to change the focus:

> Investors will **consider** active funds (to be) too expensive.
>   Investors will **find** active funds (to be) too expensive.